# How to determine if a thread is main thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, programmers can change the name of main thread. So how to determine if a thread is main thread?

```
package bj.thread;

public class ThreadApp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("The main thread name is %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.currentThread().setName("not-main");
        System.out.printf("The main thread name is %s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

The output:

```
The main thread name is main
The main thread name is not-main
```

Comment: Why does it matter to you if a thread is the main thread or not?

Comment: There is nothing special about the main thread in Java, other than that it was the thread that called the `main` method of the application. Applications can continue running long after the main-thread stopped running.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isMainThread(){
    return Thread.currentThread().getId() == 1;
}
```

*Disclaimer : it's not stated in the doc that id == 1 => it's the main thread*

Comment: Warning: if the javadocs don't state this, then you should not rely on it.  It may not be true for all Java implementations, and it may change in a future implementation.

Answer (score 0):

More common decision is save Thread ID as soon as your program is started in `main()` method and compare it with other Thread ID when you will need it

P.S If you geek enough you can use special Java Reflection API and insert you check code into `main()` function begin any code. It can be useful when you try to use 3rd-party code.